# Problems using Slick jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement the Slick jQuery.

It comes with jQuery < ver. 1.7, but requires ver. 1.7, so for the moment I'm using ver. 2.1.4.

I've uploaded my solution here: http://jsjensen.dk/slick/. I have two problems.

1) The first problem I have is that it won't use the provided Slick font embedded at the top in slick-theme.css. So you can't see the arrows next to the slide content, but they are actually there.

2) The second problem is that it adds some weird blue outlines around the slider content when I click on one (even though they're not links) and also when I scroll/click through the slider.

Can anyone help with this? I try to do everything correct and have been looking in to the working code of the Slick slider official page, but it doesn't work for me somehow.

Is the Slickr framework possibly to old already?

Comment: 2nd problem can be solved by `outline:0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: #000;
}

.slick-slide.slick-active {
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But can you explain to me how it works on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ when it doesn't work in my example? Do they use this additional code somewhere, but forgot to include it in the download maybe? I'm happy it works, but I'm also curious to know why :-)